# Dynamic buttons with attributes through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alright, I can generate a button with code of the form

```
var temp = "<button type=\"button\" class=\"dynBtn\" id=\"anID\">Here!</button>";
$('#myDiv').append(temp).click(function(){
    window.alert("Hello! My id is " + this.id);
});
```

And then on runtime this is not really working since I get as an answer for the id to be "myDiv". On the other hand, I also tried to use something like this:

```
$('#myDiv').append(temp).click(dynButtonClicked(this));
```

where dynButtonClicked is defined separately as

```
function dynButtonClicked (aButton) {
    window.alert("Hey, my id is " + aButton.id);    
};
```

However, this way, the button is clicked when the page is loaded, the id is 'undefined' and moreover, no matter how many times I click the button I get no further alerts (apart from the one I got while the page was loading). So, how can I do this right?

I guess ideally I would like to give a name for the class of all the buttons that are generated on runtime and then when clicking any of those to handle them somewhere in the

```
$(document).ready(...)
```

function. But please, go ahead and tell me your thoughts. In fact, later on, through interaction I may want to delete the buttons or disable them. So, I am looking for something robust. Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: `click` expects a function, you're passing `undefined`. Also `append` doesn't give you the element that was appended, it still is the container.

Comment: I am not sure what you are suggesting as a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how to do it the jQuery way:

```
var $button = $('<button/>', {
  type: 'button',
  'class': 'dynBtn',
  id: 'anID',
  text: 'Here!',
  click: function() {
    window.alert('Hello! My id is '+ this.id);
  }
});

$button.appendTo('#myDiv');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. This works nicely with delegation as well. Have a great day! :)

Comment: Actually, this seems not to be entirely correct either. If we change the statement to:
window.alert('Hello! My class is ' + this.class + ' and my id is '+ this.id);
the class returned is undefined. Suggestion?

Comment: Because it's `this.className`.

Comment: Sorry for my confusion. Thank you for your time. Have a great day!

Comment: Hey @elclanrs: is there a way to convert the jQuery object to an html string (call it html) and then append it to div using a statement of the form document.getElementById(myDiv).innerHTML = html; ? This would be great for me.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `.append()` doesn't return the appended element, you can use `.appendTo()` in this case:

```
$(temp).appendTo('#myDiv').on('click', function() {
    window.alert("Hello! My id is " + this.id);
});
```

If you are adding many elements to the DOM, it would be better to use event delegation instead.

```
$('#myDiv').on('click', '.appendedElement', fn);
```

Comment: Thank you. This is working, and the delegation is also working. However, if we change the argument of alert to:
'Hello! My class is ' + this.class + ' and my id is '+ this.id
then the class is not printed! Do you have a hint on why is that? Of course it seems strange, because earlier jQuery selects the button based on its class through delegation ...

Comment: Did you read my comment? It's not `this.class` it's `this.className`.

Comment: @MightyMouse Because there is no `.class` property, it's `.className`.

Comment: Thank you for your time undefined. I accepted the response by elclanrs b/c he has lower reputation. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Use on(), do like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //in here you put the event for all elements with dynBtn class
  $(document).on("click",".dynBtn",function(){dynButtonClicked();});
});

function dynButtonClicked (aButton) {
    window.alert("Hey, my id is " + aButton.id);    
};

//and append the button anytime you want
var temp = "<button type=\"button\" class=\"dynBtn\" id=\"anID\">Here!</button>";
$('#myDiv').append(temp);
```

Comment: I am sorry but this is not even generating a button.