# Suggested method for generating html with different elements on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamically-generated

I want to generate dynamically a few elements (not known in advance how many) and glue them together and essentially extend a div, say with id "myDiv". For demonstration purposes, say that a client receives a message to generate a list of three buttons on the fly by extending the div.

I am stuck though, because I generate the list like this

```
var temp = "<ul>";
for (i = 0; i < someTimes; i++) {
    temp += "<li>some text <div id=\"button" + i + "\"></div></li>";
}
temp += "</ul>";
```

then do

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = html;
```

and in order to generate each button my initial intention was to then [do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19072478/dynamic-buttons-with-attributes-through-jquery#19072533) in order to append each button to the appropriate div that was generated on the fly in the while loop. But this thing does not work. Perhaps there are a few things here for a newbie like me;

1. Is there a Javascript example that I could use inside the for loop in order generate the buttons dynamically, give them the id that I want and delegate them?
2. Should I convert the first part from Javascript to jQuery and then do both things simultaneously with jQuery? How (in this example)?
3. Is there a good reference for these things?

Thank you in advance for your time. I do not expect answers to all three questions but I would like to get an answer on how to achieve this mini goal as a guideline on how to continue my work.

Comment: using jquery will always be better

Comment: Thanks. However, how would such a simple thing be done in jQuery?

Comment: there are many examples online and many questions here in stackoverflow. 
a good place to start with will be 
http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: what would the receiving message look like? what format json,xml?

Comment: The receiving message would be a json indicating say how many times we have to iterate (it is actually more than that, but I believe this suffices for the example).

Answer (score 2):

Well , I could reference you to a library plugin for templating.

But I'm pretty sure that it can be done with a a few lines of code (poor man's templating engine ( crockford) :

```
if (!String.prototype.supplant) {
    String.prototype.supplant = function (o) {
        return this.replace(/{([^{}]*)}/g,
            function (a, b) {
                var r = o[b];
                return typeof r === 'string' || typeof r === 'number' ? r : a;
            }
        );
    };
}
```

So how it will work :

This will be your structure : *(technically you can(and should) put it under text/template section)*

`var t= '<tr data-symbol="{Symbol}"><td>{Symbol}</td><td>{Price}</td><td>{DayOpen}</td></tr>';`

This is the binding part :

`t.supplant({Symbol:'s',Price:2,DayOpen:3})`

[**live example**](http://jsbin.com/iPUjAxe/2/edit)

Answer (score 1):

This is how it's done with Jquery

```
var $ul = $('<ul></ul>');
for (i = 0; i < someTimes; i++) {
    $ul.appent("<li>some text <div id='button" + i + "'></div></li>");
}
$('#myDiv').append($ul);
```

Comment: I really like this approach for a beginner like me, but then right after your code I would like to write down another loop where I generate the actual button and append it on the divs that were generated with your loop. So, I generate the buttons on the fly (every iteration like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19072478/dynamic-buttons-with-attributes-through-jquery#19072533), then generate a var tempID = '#button' + i; and then (end of each iteration) I am doing $(tempID).append($aButton); But this is not working.

Comment: you should post your code or even better make a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) because in general the solution you propose should work

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) in `JQuery`. The syntax is:

```
$(content).appendTo(selector)
```

The example on the jquery docs page is:

```
<h2>Greetings</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>
  <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
</div>

$( "<p>Test</p>" ).appendTo( ".inner" );
```

EDIT: based on comment..

```
<div class="placeholder"></div>

$( "your generated html" ).appendTo($(".placeholder"));
```

Comment: What I am trying to say is that the div with the class "inner" is going to be generated on the fly. So, no, this is not really working for me. That was my idea: to generate the html say with the divs, then use document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = html; and after that part when the divs are ready I would append to "inner". Makes sense?